# OpenVINO accuracy checker directly compare results to annotations?

Tags: model, openvino

https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/tools/accuracy_checker/README.md

Keeping in mind the above, I have the following question

I have an external model, which I have already trained and got the corresponding results. Is it possible to do the accuracy check for the results directly, rather than running the model again on the input images?

So this is what I mean is

`accuracy_check -c path/to/configuration_file -m /path/to/models -s /path/to/source/data -a /path/to/annotation`

should be replaced with

`accuracy_check -c path/to/configuration_file -r path/to/model_execution_results -a /path/to/annotation`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, running the accuracy check for the results directly instead of running the model again on the input images is not possible.

You may refer [here](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_tools_accuracy_checker_configs.html) for further infos on how to correctly use the Accuracy Checker Tool.